# Dictionary with iterations

Tags: python

I’m supposed to make a function that iterates through a string and makes a dictionary of the types of characters inside it. For example, `{upper : 3, lower: 3, spaces :2}`. I can create the keys but I can’t seem to count them right. These are the strings I have to use :

```
print(count_types("aabbccc"))
print(count_types("ABC 123 doe ray me!"))
```

Comment: You should include an example of your code, we won't have any idea of why you aren't counting right without it.

Answer (score 5):

#### The simple approach

```
from collections import defaultdict


def count_types(string):
    types = defaultdict(int)
    for char in string:
        if char.islower():
            types['lower'] += 1
        elif char.isupper():
            types['upper'] += 1
        elif char.isspace():
            types['space'] += 1
        elif char.isdigit():
            types['digit'] += 1
    return types

            
print(count_types("ABC 123 doe ray me!"))
```

**Result:**

> `{'upper': 3, 'spaces': 4, 'lower': 8}`

---

#### The `Counter` approach

```
from collections import Counter
import string


FIELD_NAMES = {
    **{char: 'lower' for char in string.ascii_lowercase},
    **{char: 'upper' for char in string.ascii_uppercase},
    **{char: 'space' for char in string.whitespace},
    **{char: 'digit' for char in string.digits},
}


def count_types(string):
    types = Counter(map(FIELD_NAMES.get, string))
    del types[None]
    return types
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to supplement @Infinity's great answer with this example based on `re`:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict


s = 'ABC 123 doe ray me!'
res = defaultdict(int)
res['upper'] = len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', s))
res['lower'] = len(re.findall(r'[a-z]', s))
res['spaces'] = len(re.findall(r' ', s))
res['digits'] = len(re.findall(r'\d', s))
print(res)
```

Edited:

Also I wrote such a compact creative code with `itertools.starmap`:

```py
import re
from itertools import starmap

s = 'ABC 123 doe ray me!'
counts = starmap(lambda pattern: len(re.findall(pattern, s)),
                 ((r'[A-Z]',), (r'[a-z]',), (r' ',), (r'\d',)))
res = {}
res['upper'], res['lower'], res['spaces'], res['digits'] = counts
print(res)
```

Maybe someone would find it interesting (or too unreadable).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
import string


def classify(char):
    for func, char_type in [(str.isupper, 'upper'),
                            (str.islower, 'lower'),
                            (str.isspace, 'space'),
                            (str.isdigit, 'digit'),
                            (lambda c: c in string.punctuation, 'punctuation')
                            ]:
        if func(char):
            return char_type

    return 'unknown'


def count_types(input_string):
    return Counter((classify(char) for char in input_string))
```

```
print(count_types("aabbccc"))
Counter({'lower': 7})
```

```
print(count_types("ABC 123 doe ray me!"))
Counter({'lower': 8, 'space': 4, 'upper': 3, 'digit': 3, 'punctuation': 1})
```